# How to prove an inequality

Tags: coq

How do I prove this in Coq? Tactic "omega" does not work. Neither does "lia".

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Psatz.
Open Scope Z.
Lemma ge1:
forall b k: Z,
b>=1 -> k>=1 -> k < b/2 -> Zabs (b*b-2*b*k-k*k) >=1.
intros b k.
intros H1 H2 H3.
omega.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you write down an informal proof of this theorem using ordinary mathematical language? Coq isn't an automated theorem prover. It isn't designed to find proofs for you. Coq is a proof assistant. It is designed to help you write down formal proofs of things that you already know how to prove informally. If you can perhaps edit your question to include the main idea of the proof in ordinary mathematical language, then we can more productively discuss how to proceed with the proof in Coq.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just tried to see if it would work. 

I buit an informal proof as follows: (i) since b and k are naturals, then Zabs (...) is also a natural (ii) Zabs can´t be zero, for its roots are always irrational (iii) the leat value of Zabs(...) is 1 (make b=2 and k=5). Thus, Zabs(...) is equal to or greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since an absolute value is always positive, what you want to prove is that the argument of Z.abs cannot be zero. But since with the given ranges it can become positive and negative you need a number theoretical argument. Lia (and nia) can only conclude, when you can argue with inequalities, say if you could prove that the argument of Zabs is always >=1 or <=-1, which is not the case.

When you solve "b b - 2 b k - k k = 0" for k you get "k=(+-sqrt(2)-1)*b". To show that there are no k and b which fulfil this equation you need the irrationality of sqrt(2). Lia does not know about sqrt(2).

Comment: Yes, that's what I did (see my comment above). Thanks.